# Limit extruding by face

Tags: modeling

I am modelling for 3D printing. I want to the drop faces to that slope.

[image]

How it is possible to limit extruding by the slope to avoid cutting through like in the second image?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/D5336

Comment: i am newbie, it is a to-do or i can install it? Cant find a way to do it

Comment: It is a to-do, it is not available yet to end users

Comment: So sad, i am right, there is no way to do it by current tools?